# Unable to update XCode: Requires MacOS 10.15.4 or later

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, macos-catalina, mobile-development

I am developing applications for iPhones. i have xcode version 11.2.1. My iPhone is updated to iOS 14 and now i am no longer able to run apps in iPhone via XCode, because it says I need to have an updated version of XCode. I visited App Store XCode page, and it says below

> Requires MacOS 10.15.4 or later

My MacOS Version is 10.15.2. I am unable to update MacOS because I only have 14 GB left in my hard drive. My hard drive is only 121 GB. To install MacOS, it is asking me for 20.81 GB free eventhough the download is like 4.8GB

[image]

I ran DaisyDisk check (I have paid version) below is the result.

[image]

Then

[image]

For your note, XCode and Android studio has taken most space. I am using this laptop mainly for Mobile development.

[image]

Now I have 2 problems.

1. Unable to update XCode because MacOS is old
2. Unable to update MacOS because no space is left.

I have removed the XCode derived data, checked for local snapshots, uninstalled some applications, removed Android emulators and still only managed to free just 14.4 GB. The only other thing I can think of is removing MS Office package which will clear 6GB.

However if MacOS update is asking for 20.1 GB, I am not sure how much XCode will ask for. Maybe another 12-20 GB.

What should I do to update MacOS and Xcode at this stage? After removing so many files and few applications, I clearly fear to remove more things blindly without knowing whether it will help or not to update both MacOS and XCode. If it does, I have no problem. If it helps, I have 1 TB external hard disk which I have not used yet.

Answer (score 0):

hey if you have iOS 14 than you should update Xcode to Xcode 12 , talking about space , open terminal and type command `xcrun simctl delete unavailable` this will delete old simulators and data related to it which you don't need .Now go to Mac app store and download DevCleaner its an app for Xcode users ,
Open it Check the box of Derived Data and Old simulator and device logs and click clean , unfold the Device support option in that app(DevCleaner) ->iOS-> see check the older iOS version and delete it ,
Now you will have enough space . Install newer versions of macOS , Xcode and iOS(on iPhone) and let me know how it goes , I also have more tips

Comment: I ran the app you mentioned. This is what I got, really not sure whether it is safe to delete them - https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYrP4.png

Comment: Also will I have to delete more and more to update XCode, after updating Catalina?

Comment: hey @PeakGen ,yes you have selected correct ones delete it , they are older versions you no longer require it .  and have you run that command in terminal ??

Comment: I havent run the command in terminal. The software you mentioned seems to detect it and it shows no old simulators.

Comment: @PeakGen , the software doesn't show old simulators man the command deletes the old simulator , have you deleted the things that you selected in software ?? also run that command in the terminal it should save some enough space for you

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I managed to update the MacOS. Now the issue is XCode. I have 18-19 GB free but the App Store says `Not enough space to update XCode`

Comment: hey @PeakGen, same way find ways to do so in android studio , read this to free up more with xcode https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/saving-space-as-an-ios-developer-c09f5b6af395 , If not possible and delete Xcode for now update to macOS Big Sur and than reinstall. it